# neural networks - classifier with extra class for empty inputs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

When creating a multiclass neural network, when do we need to include an extra class for "no object of interest here" inputs?

In most tutorials and articles I have read there was no explanation or additional thought put into the cases where the network will receive an input that shouldn't be classified as something of interest. For me this is more apparent in CNNs, where frames from a video feed are inputted to the network. Obviously not every frame will contain an object needed to be classified. Even in the basic cats vs dogs examples I haven't read about an extra class for handling empty frames.

In the case where no extra class is used, will the probability distribution of softmax output give a relatively evenly distributed prediction, for example if we have 3 classes: `[class1, class2, class3]`, will an empty frame be predicted as `[0.33, 0.33, 0.33]`?

Also if a network is very confident in its predictions what's to stop it from outputting a prediction that is confidently wrong like `[0.9, 0.1, 0.0]`? This may be above a threshold of say 0.85 and thus we get an incorrectly classified frame.

What should be done to avoid such situations?